# Which app is open when my is on background?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing focusing iOS app on swift5, Xcode 10.3
I found  function applicationDidEnterBackground
but I can't find if there is any possible way to check which program user opened while my was on background?
Can I know was it calculator or instagram?

Comment: *Can I know was it calculator or instagram?* You can't.

Comment: nope, that is none of the app's business.

Comment: but there is the Forest app(app for focusing) wich detects somehow

Answer (score 1):

Apps on iOS are sandboxed and can not directly communicate with other apps directly. There are some API's in the iOS SDK which allows some interaction, mostly audio, share of items.

Apple does not expose to you app if an other app is launched, so checking that an other is launched is not possible.